# Is there a way to lint Terraform?

Tags: terraform, linting

I'm hoping there is something to pick up when I have misspelled variables and comments to save me some time when I'm checking my code and reduce the potential for any errors.

I normally use IntelliJ IDE for Terraform on a MAC but also have VS code set up that I can use.

Is there a plugin for either I could use or even a different tool?
I imaging variable might be difficult to lint due as I use underscores to separate words in my variable names so the tool would need to know to treat underscores as white space for linting purposes.

Comment: Have you tried the Hashicorp Terraform plugin for VSCode? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform

Answer (score 11):

[`terraform fmt`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/fmt.html)

> The `terraform fmt` command is used to rewrite Terraform configuration files to a canonical format and style.

Comment: I already use that.

Comment: Thanks anyway though.

I'm after something to spell check for me.

I use terraform fmt to formate
run terraform plan to check it should run.

But for spelling, I currently do git compare with branch then look through each bit I changed and copy all my comments and variable names I'm not 100% sure about to word and change any seportors for spaces then see if anything gets highlighted.
It's just really not a time-efficient process for that part of it.

Comment: @doug it might be easier using an IDE that has spell check (or a plugin thereof).

Comment: The issue I had when I last tried that in VS code was the spell check plugin I used thought all the resources were misspelled as it couldn't pick out words separated by underscores.

So I need it to treat   -   .  and _ as if they were spaces so it can tell if the words separated by them are spelled correctly.

Comment: Sorry but this is not linting, this is putting something in canonical format as stated but it is not a linter

Answer (score 5):

The tools that we have include in our Terraform pipelines to check code quality and best practises are;

1. [Tflint](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint)
2. [TFSec](https://github.com/tfsec/tfsec)
3. [Checkov](https://www.checkov.io/)

This way any issues get highlighted early at the MR stage.

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: you can also hook all these up with pre-commit, which is a really nice way to check a commit each time :)

Answer (score 1):

VSCode has a Terraform Linter "l2fprod.terraform-fork"
Have NOT tried it.  Did a simple search terra + lint.
HTH
DrewBai

Answer (score 1):

You can use tflint project. It has lot of plugins for cloud providers.
https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint